# How to create Tizen Web Application project with Angular?

Tags: angular, tizen, tizen-web-app, tizen-emulator

For start: I know Angular and this is my first time when I want to write something on Tizen.

I want to start writing Tizen Web Application in Angular (7.x.x) (Samsung TV)

After instalations of Tizen Studio and extensions I have created starter project like in picrure below. I don't know how to add angular to this project.

Here is how to create [angular application](https://developer.tizen.org/ko/community/tip-tech/introduction-angular-2-tizen) but nothing about tizen.

How to add angular to Tizen Web Application and run in Tizen Web Simulator Application (Samsung TV)?

[image]

I have tried:

- Creating Tizen Web Application and add angular build files and modify index.html.
- https://medium.com/@lahtela/writing-a-tizen-watch-application-with-angular-6-cd7d788fef95 (failed build)

Answer (score -1):

I think it help you to use Angular in Tizen.
Refer to attached sample app. 
You will see a build error, but, it can be fixed easily by changing Icon file name in config.xml.

[Tip & Tech in developer.tizen.org - Creating a complete Currency Calculator application in AngularJS for Tizen](https://developer.tizen.org/community/tip-tech/creating-complete-currency-calculator-application-angularjs-tizen-%E2%80%93-part-1)

Comment: This project is for AngularJS, I have no problem with application in JS. Problem starts with typescript and generated structure of angular app 2. I have tried to use generated libs but that was not working form me.